# Move Gameobject generating Objects based on Data

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, animation

I am generating gameobjects (spheres) based on coordinates, which are stored in a .csv file. I have a Gameobject with a Single Sphere as primitive childobject. Based on the data the Object will clone this sphere 17 times and move them around. I can move the whole thing around like i want it to by accessing the parent object, but in editing mode the position of the root sphere makes it uneasy to use.

The following Code makes this possible.

```
public GameObject parentObj;
public TextAsset csvFile;

[SerializeField]
private float scaleDownFactor = 10;

private int index = 0;

//class Deck : MonoBehaviour
//{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] deck;

    private GameObject[] instanciatedObjects;

    private void Start()
    {
        Fill();
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
        instanciatedObjects = new GameObject[deck.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
        {
            instanciatedObjects[i] = Instantiate(deck[i]) as GameObject;
        }
    }
//}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{     
    readCSV();
}

void readCSV()
{
    string[] frames = csvFile.text.Split('\n');

    int[] relevant = {

    0

    };

    string[] coordinates = frames[index].Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {            
        float x = float.Parse(coordinates[relevant[i] * 3]) / scaleDownFactor;
        float y = float.Parse(coordinates[relevant[i] * 3+1]) / scaleDownFactor;
        float z = float.Parse(coordinates[relevant[i] * 3+2]) / scaleDownFactor;

        //objectTest.transform.Rotate(float.Parse(fields[1]), float.Parse(fields[2]), float.Parse(fields[3]));
        //objectTest.transform.Translate(x, y, z);

        //parentObj.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        instanciatedObjects[i].transform.position = new Vector3(parentObj.transform.position.x, parentObj.transform.position.y, parentObj.transform.position.z);

        instanciatedObjects[i].transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(parentObj.transform.eulerAngles.x, parentObj.transform.eulerAngles.y, parentObj.transform.eulerAngles.z);

        //instanciatedObjects[i].transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        instanciatedObjects[i].transform.Translate(x, y, z);

    }


    if (index < frames.Length - 1)
    {
        index++;
    }
    if (index >= frames.Length -1)
    {
        index = 0;
    }

}
```

Here is a Screenshot:

[image]

So my question is:
How can I set the Position of this Sphere to one of the moving points, without changing the position of the cloned objects? Since all behave based on the BaseSphere?

Is it possible to make the BaseSphere not visible While the Objects are getting cloned or generated?

I am looking for a solution, that makes it easier to move the datagenerated Object around in Editor.

I would appreciate any kind of input.

Answer (score 0):

Make all Spheres children of `Empty Gameobject` (for example. `Sphere_root`) and use this for moving Spheres.

Also check `Scriptable Objects`. It is simple and very quick method to manage data in Unity.

@Edit

```
 public void Fill()
    {
        instanciatedObjects = new GameObject[deck.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
        {
            instanciatedObjects[i] = Instantiate(deck[i]) as GameObject;
            instanciatedObjects[i].transform.parent = Baumer; // or Sphere Root or somehing else.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a Look at the Screenshot. So you mean I should create another empty gameobject inside "bäumer" called sphere_root. and inside of the sphere root i should put the basic sphere object, which then is the base for the generated spheres?